# What is the difference between my variable name and 'it' when using 'let' in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, null, let, kotlin-null-safety

In the following code snippet, what is the difference between the two Codeblocks?
If I check with `println(name==it)`, that returns true, so they must be referencing the same object, right?

However, when the name variable has a value, everything works, but once I set it to null, Codeblock 1 works (meaning, the let block simply will not be executed), but Codeblock 2 throws an error. Why does kotlin not just skip/ignore Codeblock 2, when `name`is null?

```
fun main() {
    
    var name:String? = "Cedric"
    //name = null
    
    //Codeblock 1
    name?.let{
        println("The length of name is ${name.length}")
    }
    
    //Codeblock 1
    name?.let{
        println("The length of name is ${it.length}")
    }
    
}
```

Thank you very much, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code block 2 actually gives a compile-time error, while code block 1 doesn't. I think it's just a weird linting bug, as the two cases should be treated the same.

Comment: As another Kotlin learner, am I getting it right that the whole let block should not be executed in the first place when name is null? In that case, it really is quite strange.

Comment: why 2 code block gives a compile-time error? He should not, also as a first one.

Comment: It looks like if `name = null` is uncommented, then the compiler replaces `name` with `null`, since the type hint shows that type of `it` is `Nothing`

Comment: @Fantailed It won't be executed in either case. But the linter will still check that the code inside the blocks are syntactically correct. And if `name = null` is uncommented, it gives an error in case 2 but not in case 1. Even though `name` is smart-casted to `kotlin.Nothing` in case 1, it still lets you fetch `String.length` from it, which I don't think it should do. Or maybe I'm wrong and smart-casting is supposed to work like this for some reason.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Not for me: https://i.imgur.com/30bXHmb.png

Comment: Oh, you're right. I think @IR42 has it figured out. You can replace `name = null` with `if (true) name = null` and it behaves as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this, you discovered bug in compiler. I have two different behaviors in Android studio and in IntelliJ.
In case when it is compiled, compiled code is optimized and it looks like this when it is decompiled:

```
   public final void main() {
      Object name = "Cedric";
      name = (String)null;
   }
```

In case when it is not compiled I get an error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtNameReferenceExpression
File being compiled: (12,45) in D:/Projekti/kotlin playground/src/Main.kt
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitSimpleNameExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:326)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:3258)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.accept(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitExpression(KtVisitor.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(KtVisitor.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(KtVisitor.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.accept(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:304)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:409)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeAppend(ExpressionCodegen.java:4108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeAppendForEntries(ExpressionCodegen.java:874)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.lambda$visitStringTemplateExpression$6(ExpressionCodegen.java:864)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(CallGenerator.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallBasedArgumentGenerator.generateExpression(CallBasedArgumentGenerator.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ArgumentGenerator.generate(ArgumentGenerator.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2534)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2506)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1731)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureGenerationStrategy.doGenerateBody(ClosureGenerationStrategy.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:654)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:479)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureCodegen.generateClosureBody(ClosureCodegen.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureCodegen.generateBody(ClosureCodegen.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:1038)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:1008)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitLambdaExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:999)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitLambdaExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:304)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(CallGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallBasedArgumentGenerator.generateExpression(CallBasedArgumentGenerator.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ArgumentGenerator.generate(ArgumentGenerator.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2534)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2506)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CoercionValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue$StackValueWithSimpleReceiver.putReceiver(StackValue.java:2089)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putReceiver(StackValue.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1731)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:654)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:479)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackagePartCodegen.generateBody(PackagePartCodegen.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:145)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$Companion.compileSingleFile(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:335)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$Companion.getBytecodeForFile(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$UpdateBytecodeToolWindowTask.processRequest(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$UpdateBytecodeToolWindowTask.processRequest(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask$1$1.run(LongRunningReadTask.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:869)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask.lambda$runWithWriteActionPriority$0(LongRunningReadTask.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask.runWithWriteActionPriority(LongRunningReadTask.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask$1.run(LongRunningReadTask.java:110)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Couldn't find descriptor for 'length'
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitSimpleNameExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitSimpleNameExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNameReferenceExpression.accept(KtNameReferenceExpression.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:304)
    ... 105 more
```

It looks like compiler does not follow optimization of code. So even if it should or should not compile, there are two different behaviors which means that one of those is not correct.